# Decomposition of an array structure including 3D model face element and node using Python or Pytorch?

Tags: python, arrays, pytorch, graphics, 3d

I'm having trouble saving the 3D model. The current way my 3D model is read in and processed is as follows:

By directly reading into the 3D model file, I can get the nodes and facets of the model. For example,

```
>>> vertices
[[0.2, 0.2, 0.3],
 [0.3, 0.4, 0.1],
 [0.1, 0.5, 0.1],
...]
>>> faces
[[1, 2, 3],
 [1, 3, 4],
...]
```

where `vertices` is the XYZ coordinates of each node, and `face` is the node index that makes up each triangle face.

When working with a 3D model, I would merge the two into 1 array in the following way,

```
face_vertices = vertices[faces]
```

Specifically, suppose the 3D model has 200 facets and 100 nodes, then the dimensions of these arrays are as follows,

```
>>> vertices.shape
(100, 3)
>>> faces.shape
(200, 3)
>>> face_vertices.shape
(200, 3, 3)
```

This makes it easier for me to deal with it. However, when I'm done with that, I need to decompose the `face_vertices` into `vertices` and `faces` and write them to the file. During processing, `vertices` change, but the `faces` remains the same. Is there any way to do this decomposition efficiently in Python or PyTorch? The array structure I'm currently using is `torch.tensor`.

Thanks for any reply.